# OpenGL VBO not working (C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

When I'm trying to draw a triangle by using VBO + indices it's not working

```
   vertices.push_back(0.5f);
   vertices.push_back(-0.5f);
   vertices.push_back(-2.0f);
   vertices.push_back(-0.5f);
   vertices.push_back(-0.5f);
   vertices.push_back(-2.0f);
   vertices.push_back(0.5f);
   vertices.push_back(-0.5f);
   vertices.push_back(-2.0f);

   indices.push_back(0);
   indices.push_back(1);
   indices.push_back(2);


   GLuint bufferID,bufferID2;

   glGenBuffers(1,&bufferID);
   glGenBuffers(1,&bufferID2);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,bufferID);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,bufferID2);
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(GLfloat)*3,&vertices[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW);

   glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

   glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,0);
   glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,indices.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,&indices[0]);

   glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

   glDeleteBuffers(1,&bufferID);
   glDeleteBuffers(1,&bufferID2);
```

but drawing a point with VBO it's working

```
vertices.push_back(0.5f);
vertices.push_back(-0.5f);
vertices.push_back(-2.0f);

GLuint bufferID;

glGenBuffers(1,&bufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,bufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(GLfloat)*3,&vertices[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW);



glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,0);

glPointSize(100.0f);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,0,1);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glDeleteBuffers(1,&bufferID);
```

I already read through some tutorials and other posts, but nothing works.
mby I'm not using the indices correctly ?

anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561165/rendering-kinect-point-cloud-with-vertex-buffer-object-vbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of the problems @ratched_freak already covered in his answer (wrong size passed to `glBufferData` for vertices, `glBufferData` not called for index buffer, and updating the last argument to `glDrawElements` accordingly), you have another problem. Take a close look at your coordinates:

```
vertices.push_back(0.5f);
vertices.push_back(-0.5f);
vertices.push_back(-2.0f);
vertices.push_back(-0.5f);
vertices.push_back(-0.5f);
vertices.push_back(-2.0f);
vertices.push_back(0.5f);
vertices.push_back(-0.5f);
vertices.push_back(-2.0f);
```

The first and third vertex are the same. So you have a degenerate triangle.

Answer (score 2):

you only pass 3 floats to the VBO you want to pass more:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(GLfloat)*vertices.size(),&vertices[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

and when you have bound the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` the void* in glDrawElements is relative to the bound buffer:

```
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint)*indices.size(), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

and always check glGetError when you have problems, it will help understand at which calls you start going wrong.

Comment: glGenBuffers(1,&bufferID);
   glGenBuffers(1,&bufferID2);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,bufferID);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,bufferID2);
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(GLfloat)*vertices.size(),&vertices[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW);
   glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(GLuint)*indices.size(),&indices[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW);

 glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
   glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,0);
   glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,indices.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
   glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

still doesn't work. hmm
also got no error from glGetError

Comment: nvm it works! i had wrong coordinates in my vector -> for the triangle